# Unclear compile time error when using std::iterator_traits<>

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator

There's a code that gives an error, which is completely unclear to me.
What I want is to pass a pointer to struct/class member through an `iterator_traits`.

```
template<typename Iter, typename S>
S mean(Iter begin, const Iter& end, S std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type::* v)
{
    //...
}
```

But even at the declaration of this templated function, MSVS2015 gives following error on the code above:

> Error C2653   'value_type': is not a class or namespace name

However, without `iterator_trais<...>` i.e.

```
template<typename Iter, typename S>
S mean(Iter begin, const Iter& end, S Iter::value_type::* v)
{
    //...
}
```

everything compiles properly.

Why it cannot recognize `value_type` as a class name ?

Compiler bug ?

Comment: @KerrekSB why do I have to drop the final :: ?? it is required , because I'm passing pointer to class member !

Comment: Oh, OK, maybe give a bit more detail, or an example?

Comment: @KerrekSB example of usage does not matter here. Just declaring this function already gives that error

Comment: @KerrekSB but ok anyway. I'll bring some example of how it should be used. `struct Type { double a; };  std::vector<Type> collection; double res = mean(collection.begin(), collection.end(), &Type::a); `

Comment: Yeah, I see, you want to form a type like `int X::*` and make the `int` parametric. Here you go: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3jWG56cyEeLPLOgB

Comment: Why not try adding `typename` before the `iterator_traits`? Because I think scoped types which are dependent on a type parameter will need this keyword.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple syntax error. You mean:

```
template<typename Iter, typename S>
S mean(
    Iter begin,
    const Iter& end,
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type S::* v)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: hmm this compiles. But why it needs to put `S` after `value_type` ? I find it at least not readable

Comment: That's how the language syntax works. It's like asking why you need to put the "int" before the "main" in `int main`. I don't have an answer that will satisfy you.

Comment: on the usage like this `mean(samples.begin(), samples.end(), &MyType::a)` this gives an error: 
`Error C2784 'S mean(Iter,const Iter &,std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type S::* )': could not deduce template argument for 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type S::* ' from 'double MyType::*`

Comment: @KerrekSB I doubt that you have placed the `S` in the wrong place. It should have been the type of the third parameter, but in your code it was a name qualifier.

Comment: @ampawd: No, indeed, the type parameter may not be deducible. You either need some other way of deducing it, or you specify it explicitly, or you don't break down the template so much and just say `template <typename U> mean(U* v)` and then use some internal traits to destructure `U`.